# Error en programa: undeclared here (not in a function)

Tags: c

Estoy intentando hacer funcionar este programa en C pero me genera error. ¿Alguien sabe qué estoy haciendo mal?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#define N 1

int vector[N];
int vector_frecuencias[N][2];
int num_diferentes = 0;

void inicializa_vector_frencuencias() {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    vector_frecuencias[i][0] = 0;
    vector_frecuencias[i][1] = 0;
    }
}

void calculo_frecuencias() {
    int existe = false;
    int j;
    inicializa_vector_frencuencias();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < num_diferentes; j++) {
    if (vector_frecuencias[j][0] == vector[i]) {
    existe = true;
    break;
    }
    }
    if (existe) {
    vector_frecuencias[j][1]++;
    existe = false;
    }
    else {
    vector_frecuencias[j][0] = vector[i];
    vector_frecuencias[j][1]++;
    num_diferentes++;
    }
    }
}

int frecuencia_modal() {
    int fModal = INT_MIN;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_diferentes; i++) {
    if (vector_frecuencias[i][1] > fModal) {
    fModal = vector_frecuencias[i][1];
    }
    }
    return fModal;
}

void moda() {
    calculo_frecuencias();
    int fModal = frecuencia_modal();
    printf("Modas:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < num_diferentes; i++) {
    if (vector_frecuencias[i][1] == fModal) {
    printf("%d \t %d\n", vector_frecuencias[i][0], vector_frecuencias[i][1]);
    }
    }
}

void imprime_frecuencias() {
    printf("Frecuencias\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < num_diferentes; i++) {
    printf("%d \t %d\n", vector_frecuencias[i][0], vector_frecuencias[i][1]);
    }
}

void llenar_vector() {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    vector[i] = rand() % 10;
    }
}

void imprime_vector() {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    printf("%d - %d \n",i+1, vector[i]);
    }
}

float media_aritmetica() {
    float suma = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    suma += vector[i];
    //suma = suma+vector[i];
    }
    return suma / N;
}

void burbuja() {
    for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
    if (vector[i] > vector[j]) {
    int aux = vector[i];
    vector[i] = vector[j];
    vector[j] = aux;
    }
    }
    }
}

//0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
//mediana = (vector[4]+vector[5])/2
// División entera: 1/2 = 0
float mediana() {
    int pos = N / 2;
    float m = 0.0;
    if (N % 2 == 0) {
    m = (float)(vector[pos - 1] + vector[pos]) / 2.0;
    }
    else {
    m = vector[pos - 1];
    }
    return m;
}

float varianza() {
    float media = media_aritmetica();
    float var = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    var += pow(vector[i] - media, 2);
    }
    var /= N;
    return var;
}

float desviacionEstandar() {
    return sqrt(varianza());
}

int main() {
    llenar_vector();
    imprime_vector();
    printf("\n El valor de la varianza es: %f\n ", varianza());
    printf("\n El valor de la DS es: %f\n ", desviacionEstandar());

    return 0;
}
```

Error:

> main.c:16:15: error: 'INT_MIN' undeclared here (not in a function) int fModal = INT_MIN;
>
> main.c: In function 'calculo_frecuencias': main.c:26:16: error: 'false' undeclared (first use in this function) int existe = false;

Answer (score 6):

> main.c:16:15: error: 'INT_MIN' undeclared here (not in a function) int fModal = INT_MIN;

Te falta incluir `<limits.h>` al principio:

```
#include <limits.h>
```

> main.c: In function 'calculo_frecuencias': main.c:26:16: error: 'false' undeclared (first use in this function) int existe = false;

C no tiene la palabra reservada `false`. Es tan fácil como hacer

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```

En esa cabecera se incluyen las macros `true` y `false`.

Si no la tienes (versiones antiguas de C), basta con que, después de los `include`, lo definas tú *a mano*, preferiblemente comprobando antes que no estés compilando en C++:

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
#define true 1
#define false 0
#endif
```